# Why are Alembic environment tags Optional[str]

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm running Alembic within our application code, where we have already created the sqlalchemy engine. I can pass the engine to the env.py using the `tag` parameter. However, the definition of the Alembic command I'm calling in our application is (copied from the Alembic python package):

```
def upgrade(
    config: Config,
    revision: str,
    sql: bool = False,
    tag: Optional[str] = None,
) -> None:
```

I'm wondering why Alembic has the type restriction `Optional[str]` and not just an arbitrary type for the `tag`. I'm not enforcing these checks and things seem to work ok when passing the sqlalchemy engine for the `tag`. Is there a more appropriate way of doing what I want? I'm not sure if these types hints are specified for the `EnvironmentContext`. Or have I misunderstood these type specifications?

Comment: It means the `tag` argument can be None. Is your question why it can be None?

Comment: No, it's not. My question is why (when provided) is there a type specification at all here? I'm passing in an sqlalchemy engine and I'm getting what I want. I've clarified my question.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Have you asked the person who wrote the type annotation why they wrote it that way? (I'm not sure whether the snippet you have shown is from your own code or from some documentation or third-party code)

Comment: This is from the python Alembic library. Normally you call upgrade within your application code and a generated env.py is invoked. The default env.py creates the engine from a connection string. However, I don't want the engine creation, I want to pass in one which I've already created in the application code. I can do this, successfully it seems, using the `tag`. However, I'm wondering why `tag`s are restricted to `str`s.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the code for `upgrade`, it's impossible to say. Generally, you can say that someone would add a type hint `Optional[str]` to indicate that a.) the parameter isn't required, the function has a well-defined result if no value is provided and b.) if the parameter is set then the argument passed need to be of type `str` for the function to have a well-defined result.

Comment: YEs but someone who know the workings of Alembic might be able to tell me why this restriction is in place. I should clarify that the included code is copied from the Alembic package. I clarify this.

Comment: @Grismar often optional arguments coincide with an `Optional` type annotation but technically `Optional` simply is an alias for a union with `None` and may apply to non-optional arguments or even to optional arguments where None is not the default. (See also https://discuss.python.org/t/clarification-for-pep-604-is-foo-int-none-to-replace-all-use-of-foo-optional-int/26945/6)

Comment: So what is the expected behaviour when an `int` is passed to this function for the `tag`?

Comment: I see what you're saying @mkrieger1, but also think that's just semantics. A type value that also accepts `None` would be a suitable definition of an 'optional' parameter. After all, that's what `None` signifies - a lack of a typed value.

Comment: @Jibbityjobby if you pass an `int` to an `Optional[str]` parameter, you're counting on the `int` type to function as expected when used as a `str`. The code may be safe enough to perform the conversion for you, like having `str(tag)` and that works for `int` - but you can't count on it, since the signature is clear about expecting you to do the conversion for it. In future versions, your code might break without warning. The right thing to do would be to pass `str(your value)` to `tag`, even though it appears to work without it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. I just want to know why this restriction is in place and is it telling me indirectly that this is the wrong way to get what I want. I could serialise / deserialise everything but I would prefer to do things the right way if there is one (or at least know why Alembic have added this restriction). This is really an Alembic specific question then and it doesn't seem (thanks to you) that I've misunderstood the type specification here.

Answer (score 0):

These are `str`s since there is another field in the `Config` named `attributes`, which suffices for more arbitrary custom state. It is documented as:
"A Python dictionary for storage of additional state. This is a utility dictionary which can include not just strings but engines, connections, schema objects, or anything else."

I've yet to test, but this looks like what I'm looking for. It had initially seemed to me that `Config` was just a wrapper around the config file.